# Can I connect my own credentials database with Google Identity Platform to build custom Identity Provider for SSO - OpenID Connect authentication?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, single-sign-on, openid-connect, google-identity, openid-provider

I have my own `SQL Server` database which contains usernames/passwords for authentication. I'd like to build a custom `Identity Provider` based on this database with an `Identity Management` provider so the other applications can be registered and their users can be authenticated with `OIDC`.

I researched some tutorials and they says that some `Identity Management` providers such as: `OneLogin`, `Okta`... can integrate with our own credentials database. But for `Google Identity Platform`, I cannot find any links show how to do such a thing so far.

Could you please tell me if it is possible to integrate our own database with `Google Identity Platform`? Is there any resource links mention about this? If it is impossible, is there any alternates for integrating the database with `Cloud Platform` (e.g. `Azure` or `AWS`) or we have to build our own `Identity Provider` from scratch?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Cloud Identity Platform](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs). You can define external identity provider and even a [custom identity provider](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/oidc).

However, this solution implies that your own SQL database is behind an Identity Provider OIDC compliant.

In addition, you will be able to authenticate your users to access to your application. You can't use this authentication to interact directly with Google Cloud API, only with YOUR application.

Comment: Hi @guillaume blaquiere, thank for your answer, but actually I don't see any sections of the pages you sent me mentions about the own database configuration. It seems Google Identity Platform can be only used with FireBase? Am I missing something?

Comment: You can't provide your own database. You have to provide your own  Identity Provider OIDC compliant. When you have your own Identity provider, managed by yourselves and plugged to your database, you can connect Cloud Identity Platform on this custom OIDC.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Identity Platform Admin SDK to manage Security Assertion Markup Language (SAML) 2.0 and [OpenID Connect (OIDC) provider configurations](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/managing-providers-programmatically#working_with_oidc_providers) programmatically. You can explore the details of OpenID Connect [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect).

I would also suggest you to explore the [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/identity/best-practices-for-federating) and guidance that help you set up federation consistently and securely. The guidance builds on the best practices for using Cloud Identity or G Suite with Google Cloud.

You might be interested in [Connecting to Cloud SQL from external applications](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/connect-external-app) running outside of Google Cloud.

Comment: Hi @Hasanul Murad, It seems I still not find the solution to use my own database in your provided links. Anyway, thank for your help.

Comment: As described by guillaume, you need to add you database to the Identity Platform, which you can make OIDC compliant.

Answer (score 0):

Use keycloak to expose your existing database as an open Id connect (OIDC) identity provider.

Then you can tell google identity platform to use your new identity provider as a federated provider as the other answers are telling you.

To do that, you need some code. You need to help keycloak translates common user patterns like get a user, list users, check password, get groups, roles etc into your database.  This is done implementing a StorageProvider with the capabilities (user lookup, password update, user creation etc) you need.

There is an JDBC provider ready, where you only provide the correct queries. Check keycloak documentation. You only need to implement the ones you need (eg: don’t implement user creation through keycloak if you don’t need to create users through keycloak admin interface; don’t implement password change if your users manage their passwords via your existem infrastructure; and so on). For this use case (google authentication) user lookup and password validation are enough.

Okta will not help you here, but that was possible directly with Auth0 (custom database connector).

So you either implement your own OIDC (open if connect) with keycloak or look for a cloud identity solution capable of custom database connection and them expose it to google.